# Remove Combobox winrt flayout heading

Tags: combobox, windows-runtime, styles, winrt-xaml

In winrt windows phone app when you have more than 5 items in a combobox, it opens up on a full screen. And on top its written 'Choose an item'.

I want to remove this heading from all my combo boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set PickerFlyoutBase.Title property of combobox to either with space or text of your choice. So it would be like:

```
PickerFlyoutBase.Title= " "
   or
PickerFlyoutBase.Title="Some text"
```

Comment: oh Thank God there is something I can do, but can you please tell from where I get this property? As I'm new to windows phone programming

Comment: You will find this property where you define ComboBox in xaml  <ComboBox name = "something" PickerFlyoutBase.Title= " "></ComboBox>